# Converting a string into its respective unicode ints and back only using strings and ints

Tags: java, string, unicode, chars

Well my assignment is to convert a string into its respective unicode ints, shift based on the desired encryption (left or right and how many spaces). I was able to figure this part out just fine. But then I need to enter the shifted string of unicode and convert that back into the original string entered. Here is my code. I can't figure out how to convert the unicode string back into the original string. 
**Note - I AM ONLY ALLOWED TO USE INTS AND STRINGS.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Character;

public class CSCD210_HW2
{
   public static void main(String [] args){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String str, str1 = "";  
   String encrypt, decrypt = ""; 
   int i = 0; 
   int i1 = (int)0;

      System.out.printf("Please enter a string:"); 
      str = input.nextLine();
      System.out.printf("\nPlease enter encryption format - \'left\' or \'right\'" +
      " \"space\" number of spaces:");
      encrypt = input.nextLine();
      int length = str.length();
      String spaces = encrypt.substring(encrypt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1); 
      Integer x = Integer.valueOf(spaces);   
      //encrypt
      if (encrypt.startsWith("l")){
         while (i < length){
         int uni = (int)(str.charAt(i++));
         char uni1 = (char)uni;
         int result = uni + x;
         System.out.print(result + " ");}}
      else if (encrypt.startsWith("r")){
         while (i < length){
         int uni = (int)(str.charAt(i++));
         char uni1 = (char)uni;
         int result = uni - x;
         System.out.print(result + " ");}}
      //decrypt
      System.out.printf("\nPlease enter encrypted string:");
      str1 = input.nextLine();
      System.out.printf("\n\'left\' or \'right\' \"space\" number of spaces:");
      decrypt = input.nextLine();
      int length1 = str1.length();
      String spaces1 = decrypt.substring(decrypt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
      Integer y = Integer.valueOf(spaces1);
      if (decrypt.startsWith("l")){
         while (i < length1){
         char word = (char)(str1.charAt(i++));
         int result = word + y;
         System.out.print(result);}}
      else if (decrypt.startsWith("r")){
         while (i < length1){
         char word = (char)(str1.charAt(i++));
         int result = word - y;
         System.out.print(result);}}


   }
}
```

Comment: This might help: [Unicode - The Java Tutorials > Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html)

Comment: Can you use the `char` primitive?

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to use char primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your second part does not make sense as you have the encrypted values which are basically 3 digits for a single character. You need therefore a way to convert the 3 numbers back into 1 character and not create a character per number.

Replace this with your second part:

```
  // split the input line containing the encrypted values into single tokens
  // each token represents the numerical values of a single character
  String[] tokens = str1.split("\\s");
  // reserve some space for the characters
  // char[] chars = new char[tokens.length];
  String chars = "";
  // keep track of the position
  // int pos = 0;
  for (String token : tokens)
  {
      if (decrypt.startsWith("l"))
      {
          // convert the string containing the number to integer
          Integer val = Integer.parseInt(token);
          // convert the integer back to char and apply the transformation
          // chars[pos++] = ((char)(val.intValue()+y));
          chars += ((char)(val.intValue()+y));
      }
      else
      {
          // convert the string containing the number to integer
          Integer val = Integer.parseInt(token);
          // convert the integer back to char and apply the transformation
          // chars[pos++] = ((char)(val.intValue()-y));
          chars += ((char)(val.intValue()-y));
      }
  }
  // check if everything worked as expected
  System.out.println(chars);
  // System.out.println(new String(chars));
```

@Edit:
UPDATED to the needs of the OP

Comment: Thank you for the insightful input but like I mentioned, I am only allowed to use strings and ints. I am not allowed to use arrays.

Comment: Awesome that makes much more sense. Thank you sir.